# Add the Edges of 2D array and return its answer

Tags: c++, arrays

What's wrong with my code
I Have to add all the edge values of the 2D Array.
The Function is not returning what I want. Its returning garbage value.

***Program Req Output : Add all the edges value of the 2D Array and return its answer.
You are not allowed to use Vector etc.***

Here is my Code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int rows = 3;
const int cols = 4;
void AddEdges (int arr[rows][cols])
{
    int sum = 0;
    int totalOfEdges = 0;

    int i,j;
    int k = 0;
    int l = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= cols; j++)
        {
            if (i == 1 || i == rows || j == 1 || j == cols)
            {
                sum = arr[k][l];
                totalOfEdges = sum + totalOfEdges;
            }
            l++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    cout << "Total of Edges = " << totalOfEdges << endl;
    
}

int main()
{
    int arr[3][4] = {0};
    cout << "Enter Elements for Array = \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    AddEdges(arr);
}
```

**My Output :**

[image: Output]

Comment: the first index is 0, ie valid indices are `0` till `size-1`.

Comment: how to fix that ? Sorry i know its a sikky question but i am still noob and learning

Comment: Tricky - why do you use _two_ variables per loop to iterate? Just use `k` and `l` and drop `i` and `j` - `for (k = 0; k < rows; k++)` etc ...

Comment: Thanks  a lot mates

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the Correct Code in Case Any one need it .

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int rows = 3;
const int cols = 4;
void AddEdges (int arr[rows][cols])
{
    int sum = 0;
    int totalOfEdges = 0;

    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == (rows-1) || j == 0 || j == (cols-1))
            {
                sum = arr[i][j];
                totalOfEdges = sum + totalOfEdges;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Total of Edges = " << totalOfEdges << endl;
    
}

int main()
{
    int arr[3][4] = {0};
    cout << "Enter Elements for Array = \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << "--------" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    AddEdges(arr);
}
```

Comment: Just a small simplification: Instead of `sum = arr[i][j]; totalOfEdges = sum + totalOfEdges;` you can just do `totalOfEdges += arr[i][j];`